# Using org-mode link attachment method, Windows 7

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I want to avoid copying/moving every file I want to attach to an attachment directory because this is redundant, or it forces me to use that directory as the central project directory. I might want to attach say some useful reference from an entirely different folder. So the question is, is there a way to use linking as the attachment method on Windows 7 in emacs org-mode?